# Monodroid screen dimensions

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to reference WindowManger so I can get the default screen's dimensions but I can't seem to find reference to it. (this is API 8, froyo 2.2). I even tried:

```
dynamic wm = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WindowService);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

But got an error indicating that `Object` doesn't respond to `getDefaultDisplay`.

Also I tried:

```
var wm = (IWindowManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WindowService);
Display display = wm.DefaultDisplay;
```

But I get an invalid cast exception.

Saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204326/how-to-get-screen-dimensions-in-monoandroid), but I can't resolve `WindowManager`. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: (1) The default type returned by `Context.GetSystemService()` will be a `Java.Lang.Object`, and won't have `getDefaultDisplay`, hence my answer about using `.JavaCast<T>()`. (2) `dynamic` wouldn't give you the Java members, but only C# members, so it would still need to be `DefaultDisplay` if (1) weren't in play. (3) `dynamic` + linking can be painful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WindowManager` is the [IWindowManager](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Views.IWindowManager) interface. Instead of the cast, try using the [.JavaCast<T>()](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast%3CTResult%3E) extension method:

```
var wm = context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WindowService)
    .JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
var d  = wm.DefaultDisplay;
```

You can also check out the [AccelerometerPlay sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/AccelerometerPlay/AccelerometerActivity.cs#L52).

Comment: Nice! That did it. Thank you. We've done more MT work. This is useful for cross-compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler way is

Display display = this.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;

You can get the Width and Height properties from the display object.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Android.Runtime; //for JavaCast

var windowManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
```